# how to Include another application in my application?

Tags: iphone, ios4

In my application i was supposed to include/access/bring another application which is installed in iPhone. I don't have the source code for the other application. I googled several references which says that i should include the source file of another application without ticking copy options. but the problem here is i don't have the source file of the application.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase it.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to jump the sandbox.  It is not possible.

Comment: Please tell us EXACTLY what you are trying to accomplish. There are ways to tie in to other applications but it is very case specific. So please, tell us as much as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're hoping to "embed" another application so that it appears to be part of your own then you're going to be out of luck (i.e. this cannot be done) without the source.

If you'd like to launch another application (say facebook) then you can use URL schemes, there's a good reference here: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

If you have something else in mind you'll have to rephrase the question as others have already said, it's not entirely clear.

Comment: Thank you,with clear details i will rephrase it soon, even i don't have the clear sketch yet,...is that possible to embed another application and open it independently so that it does't look to be a part of my own..?